# Is possible implement a thrid-way economy without undesired side effects, that persists in time? (Under the Austrian School of Economy)

Tags: political-economy, policy

The questions is very much in the title, but some clarification are necessary

1. For the porpourse of this question the term *third-way economy* will be defined as a economic system that tries to have what is considered "good" (by the politician of turn) the of both *capitalism* and *communism*, trought intervention in the market.
2. For the porpourse of this question the term *capitalism* will be defined as *laissez-faire*.
3. For the porpourse of this question the term *communism* will be defined as a system where the state owns the means of production.
4. The Austrian School of Economy is assumpted to be true.

Comment: Welcome to economics.se. This question is too vague and vague questions are off topic on this site. What do you consider undesired side effects in a long run? Also your definition of “third way” is vague. Capitalism or Communism are poorly defined value laden terms that are not used that much in economic literature. Unless you precisely define what you mean by those terms the question is too vague for this site.

Comment: @1muflon1 I think I fixed it.

Comment: There is no need to reopen the question, the current answer fits it perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## No, It will evolve to comunist or capitalism

The economist Ludwig von Mises in his essay [Critique of Interventionism](https://mises-media.s3.amazonaws.com/Critique%20of%20Interventionism%2C%20A_3.pdf) recalls that every measure that the goverment takes will always cause undesired consequences. There are third approaches to treat with the consequences of interventionism

1. Revert the policy: It explains by itself, no comentary needed.
2. Accept the undesired consequences: It explains by itself, no comentary needed.
3. The Third Way: It is explained below.

The Third Way approach consists in do another intervention to try fix the problems, this means that another policy was introduced with their respective undesired consequences, so the thrid way approach will repeat until you get just comunnist.

Therefore every instance that tries to implement a third way economy will naturaly lead to communist, and will never persist in time.